# jQuery change params of html tag as new row has been added

Tags: jquery, html

I have a markup like this

```
<div class="content">
<select class="form-control" id="source" data-id="0" name="test['source'][0][]">
    <option value="asdf">asdf</option>
    <option value="sda">sda</option>
    <option value="ght">ght</option>
    <option value="wer">wer</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="target" data-id="0" name="test['target'][0][]">
    <option value="ght">ght</option>
    <option value="wer">wer</option>
    <option value="sda">sda</option>
</select>    
<button type="button" class="btn add-row"> Add</button>
</div>
```

Now I want to clone the entire content of the div. So I made my jQuery like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var clone = jQuery('div.content').clone(true);
    jQuery('.add-row').click(function() {
        var parent = jQuery('div.content').last();
        clone.clone(true).insertAfter(parent); 
    });
});
```

This one is doing fine with the clone. Now if you will see the markup I have used name for select tag 
`(test['source'][0][])` and  `(test['target'][0][])` . Now I want that when the add button will be clicked the name paramaters will be also change. Like when the first row will be appned then the name will be like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="source" data-id="1" name="test['source'][1][]"></select>

<select class="form-control" id="target" data-id="1" name="test['target'][1][]"></select>
```

then after next the name will be like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="source" data-id="2" name="test['source'][2][]"></select>

<select class="form-control" id="source" data-id="2" name="test['target'][2][]"></select>
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can chain prop after cloning to change the name of select.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var clone = jQuery('div.content').clone(true);
    var i=0;
    jQuery('body').on("click",".add-row",function() {
        i++;
        var parent = jQuery('div.content').last();
        clone.clone(true).insertAfter(parent)
        .find("select").each(function(){
          var $item=$(this);
          $item.prop("name","test['"+$item.attr("id")+"']["+ i+"][]")
          .attr("data-id",i);
        });
    });
});
```

Also I changed $(".add-row").click... with  jQuery('body').on("click",".add-row",function() { ... to make it work with cloned ones.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/cebufireyere/3/edit)

Comment: `.prop("name","test['example'["+ i+"][]")` should be `.prop("name","test['example']["+ i+"][]")`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the name attribute in the click event you, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    count = 1;
    var clone = jQuery('div.content').clone(true);
    jQuery('.add-row').click(function() {
        var parent = jQuery('div.content').last();
        $(parent).find('select').each(function () {
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'source') {
                $(this).attr('name', "test['source'][" + count + "][]");
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr('name', "test['target'][" + count + "][]");
            }
        });
        count++;
        clone.clone(true).insertAfter(parent); 
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you see my updated question